# Is it possible for WiFi adapter to degrade?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

Recently i've started to get high package loss ratio while connecting to the internet on my laptop via WiFi adapter.

I made following experiment: my laptop and laptop of my friend were on the same distance from WiFi access point, both running Ubuntu 14.04, both connected to the internet via WiFi, both running `mtr 8.8.8.8`. My laptop had 70-80 % package loss on all nodes of route while my friend's laptop gets only 1-1.5 % on border with backbone provider. I thought that maybe the cause is that my friend's laptop occupies all WiFi bandwidth and it has a priority in service by WiFi access point thus WiFi access point drops my packages, but after my friend have disconnected, package loss ratio on my laptop didn't changed at all. Then i've connected to the same router via ethernet cable: everything works fine and there is no package losses. Thus it looks like that the problem is in WiFi adapter in my laptop.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on this laptop for several months and never had problems before. So i don't think that this is a driver issue.

Is it possible for WiFi adapter on my laptop to degrade because of aging or any other reason? I just can't find any other explanation.

I'm using this laptop during 4 years. Laptop of my friend is almost new.
My laptop is Asus K50IN with Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know it hasn't been bad since the day you got it?

Comment: No;  A circuit doesn't degrade.  It either works within specifications or it doesn't.  In other words it is either broken or not broken

Comment: It worked fine with the same hardware and software configuration.

Comment: Ramhound's comment is not correct.  A "circuit" typically consists of multiple components and connections.  Any component or connection within a circuit can fail.  This can result in the circuit behaving outside of designed specifications.